# Wrong output when checking whether binary tree is balanced

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, binary-tree, recursive-datastructures

I am trying to solve LeetCode problem [110. Balanced Binary Tree](https://leetcode.com/problems/balanced-binary-tree/description/):

> Given a binary tree, determine if it is **height-balanced**.

Here is my attempt:

```java
class Solution {
    boolean c = true;

    public boolean isBalanced(TreeNode root) {
        int diff = helper(root, 0);
        System.out.println(diff);
        if ((diff > 0 && diff < 2) || root == null)
            return true;
        return false;
    }

    int helper(TreeNode root, int count) {
        if (root == null) {
            return count;
        }
        int a = helper(root.left, count + 1);
        int b = helper(root.right, count + 1);
        int diff = Math.abs(a - b);
        if (diff > 1 || diff < 0)
            return count;
        return Math.max(a, b);
    }
}
```

I get the wrong result for the following input:

```
          3
         / \
        9   20
           /  \
         15    7
```

Encoded in level order: `[3,9,20,null,null,15,7]`

The expected output is true, but my code returns false.

The `TreeNode` class is as follows:

```java
class TreeNode {
    int val;
    TreeNode left;
    TreeNode right;
    TreeNode() {}
    TreeNode(int val) { this.val = val; }
    TreeNode(int val, TreeNode left, TreeNode right) {
        this.val = val;
        this.left = left;
        this.right = right;
    }
}
```

Here is the `main` code to reproduce it:

```java
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Solution solution = new Solution();

        TreeNode tree = new TreeNode(3, 
            new TreeNode(9), 
            new TreeNode(20,
                new TreeNode(15),
                new TreeNode(7)
            )
        );
        
        boolean result = solution.isBalanced(tree);
        System.out.println("result " + result); // false, but should be true
    }
```

What is my mistake?

Comment: Please add an example input, expected output, wrong output of your implementation and debugging-information.

Comment: I have added the input and output and excepted output @MrSmith42

Comment: Your sample inputs are sequences, not trees. It isn't clear how you're transforming them to trees.

Comment: Updated with the source of the code challenge and the tree that is represented by the example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with your code is that you sometimes expect `helper` to return a height and other times to return a *difference* in heights. So for instance:

- In `isBalanced` you expect `helper(root,0)` to return a difference
- In `helper` you expect `helper(root.left,count+1)` and `helper(root.right,count+1)` to return heights.
- In `helper` all `return` statements return a height, not a difference in heights.

You will need to make a clear distinction between the two. As your heights are all non-signed integers, you could reserve the value -1 to indicate that an imbalance was found, and if so, bubble this -1 up all the way to the initial call of `helper` so that `isBalanced` can know whether the whole tree is balanced or not by comparing the returned value with -1.

Not a problem, but your condition `diff < 0` will never be true, as `diff` is an absolute value.

Here is a correction of your code with that idea:

```java
class Solution {
    public boolean isBalanced(TreeNode root) {
        int result = helper(root, 0); // returns a height, or -1 if not balanced
        return result != -1;
    }

    int helper(TreeNode root,int count){
        if (root==null) {
            return count;
        }
        int a=helper(root.left,count+1);
        if (a == -1) return -1; // Don't bother continuing: we already know the tree is not balanced!
        int b=helper(root.right,count+1);
        if (b == -1) return -1; // ..idem..
        int diff=Math.abs(a-b);
        if (diff > 1) // Not balanced!
            return -1;  // Special value to indicate the tree is not balanced
        return Math.max(a, b); // The height of a balanced tree
    }
}
```